# Do this approach better than requestAction in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

`requestAction` is, mainly, used in CakePHP to render something should be found on all the application's pages or where it is not originally found.

For example: Displaying the total number of registered users at the footer of each page of a website.

In requestAction approach, this may be done by requesting an action of the UsersController that returns the count of model User. Let we name it usersCount(). This request should be in the layout used by this application's view.

In the approach that I suggest this may be done by using the User model in the AppControler and then setting a variable for the users count number, should be available in all layouts and views, for example

```
//in AppController

function beforeRender(){
  $this->uses = array('Model', 'User');
  $this->set('totalUsers',$this->User->find('count'));
}
```

So in any layout, view or element we can use $totalUsers value easily

```
<div class="footer">Currently, we have <?php echo $totalUsers;?> registered users.</div>
```

---

The word **Better** here is meant by performance. Which of this two approaches is better in performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Profile

Whenever in doubt as to the relative performance of several possibilities, don't rely on the advice of others (which may be pure speculation): *profile*.

[DebugKit](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit) comes with a [Benchmark](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit/blob/master/Console/Command/BenchmarkShell.php) shell which is a convenient means of generating benchmark information ([seige](http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/) and [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) are two more accurate/reliable alternatives):

```
$ cd my/app
$ Console/cake DebugKit.benchmark
Allows you to obtain some rough benchmarking statistics about a fully
qualified URL.

Usage:
cake debug_kit.benchmark [-h] [-v] [-q] [--n 10] [--t 100] <url>

Options:

--help, -h     Display this help.
--verbose, -v  Enable verbose output.
--quiet, -q    Enable quiet output.
--n            Number of iterations to perform. (default:
            10)
--t            Maximum total time for all iterations, in seconds.If a
            single iteration takes more than the tiemout, only one request will be
            made (default: 100)

Arguments:

url  The URL to request.

Example Use: `cake benchmark --n 10 --t 100 http://localhost/testsite`.
Note: this benchmark does not include browser render times.
```

Using a tool such as this will resolve most doubts about performance - simply set up a couple of controller actions and note the relative performance of each.

### Why limit yourself to two possibilities?

Let's assume that the question is not whether using requestAction is better than always populating a variable that may not be used (hint) but instead: *what is the best way to display <something> on all/most pages*?

Here are 2 simple rules which can probably address most problems:

1. Use caching
2. Don't ask for data you aren't going to use/ask for data only when you're going to use it

Of the two options proposed `requestAction` is more appropriate in some ways - but there are other options to achieve the same result as the example given.

### element caching

Instead of always (one way or another) getting data - get it once and don't get it again until the data is stale. For example in the layout use [element caching](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#caching-elements) so that whatever is in the element is not executed on every request:

```
echo $this->element(
    'footer',
    array(),
    "cache" => array('config' => 'element_config', 'key' => 'footer')
);
```

The contents of the `footer` element should be self sufficient, for example:

```
<?php
$User = ClassRegistry::init('User');
// $betterExample = $User->expensiveCall(); // more relevant where the call is slow
$totalUsers = $User->find('count');
?>
<div class="footer">Currently, we have <?php echo $totalUsers;?> registered users.</div>
```

In this way, the element's data is only requested when there is no cached result. By adjusting the relevant [cache config](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html#configuring-cache-class) (appropriate cache config depends on requirements - needs to be more or less realtime? use a cache config of e.g. 30 seconds; doesn't matter if it's stale? use 1 day), the frequency with which the counter updates can be modified.

Alternatively an infinite cache time can be used, and instead the cache cleared only when the value changes:

```
class User extends AppModel {

    public function updateCounterCache($keys = array(), $created = false) {
        Cache::delete('footer', 'element_config');
        return parent::updateCounterCache($keys, $created);
    }
}
```

### Other techniques?

There are other similar techniques which can be used (including using elements in conjunction with `requestAction`) - but the principle is always the same: Don't eagerly execute logic (get data) that may not be required, use caching effectively.